# I can't download Google Drive files by shared link on the folder from the server side

Tags: java, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I can't download Google Drive files by shared link on the folder - https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1zGSodg9aI48q2ER79LbJ6C-8BY3Xq-QI?usp=sharing

I tried with

```
Drive service = new Drive.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), 
      GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
      null)
  .setApplicationName("ApplicationName")
  .build();
```

and I use Files API  https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get

```
File file = service.files().get(realFileId)
  .setKey("AIzaSyCPmyt3Krb1QFca57f6v4gkHxFj5DEm8ik")
  .execute();
```

and it works for https://drive.google.com/file/d/1THGBI8GUa5_jaHpmQhZ68SHashs5h4Ef/view?usp=sharing

but what to do for  https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1zGSodg9aI48q2ER79LbJ6C-8BY3Xq-QI?usp=sharing?

UPD: The users create folders and share links, and after that, I want to load them using the server application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you have is from the Google drive web application share copy link button

[image]

this sharable link is not a true share.

The only way to be able to access a file using the google drive api would be if the file is public, if the user owns the file, or if the user has permissions on the file.

A true share of the file will add a record in the [permissions](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions) for that user with that file.

Without the user actually having a permission record on the file your not going to be able to download it with the google drive api

also note that doing a true share of a directory does not always give the user access to all files with in that directory, in my experience often you dont have access to all the files that were there before it was shared with you.

## shared with me

If you want to see all of the files shared with the current authenticated user you can use the q parameter for [file.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)

```
q=sharedWithMe%3Dtrue
```

This will list all of the files currently shared with that user.

If you want to see folders shared with the currently authenticated user you could just add folder

```
q=sharedWithMe=true and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
```

Again this will only work if the file was actually shared with you not if they used the share link created in the google drive web application.

Comment: The users create folders and share links, and I want to load them using the server application

Comment: Again the user needs to share the directory with you or your service account.  You cant do it with a shared link.

Comment: I can't be linking the shared folder to my account and finding files after, right?

Comment: Check my update.  You can use the q parameter from the file.list method to search for files that have been shared with you.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check

Comment: Let me know if you need a java file.list example I may have some code laying around.

Comment: I add access for 
drive-samples@arboreal-harbor-359512.iam.gserviceaccount.com service account but I don't see files.  FileList fileList = service.files().list()
                .setQ("sharedWithMe=true")
                .setPageSize(10)
                .execute();

Comment: fixed with scope = DriveScopes.DRIVE. file.list return my folder when .setQ("sharedWithMe=true")

Comment: How did you share them exactly?

Comment: Like user who wants to share files with the app - I clicked "Share" -> "Add people" where I added a service account https://drive.google.com/file/d/13ORBqzQovyQ82lfigmX_9-9_BKsjZ7rB/view?usp=sharing